# Unshift array element in Bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I would like to add elements to the beginning of an array instead of to the end. Is this possible in Bash?

Comment: You can hack a quick array reassignment at the beginning or end of the array, but there's nothing in bash that will insert an index. Why don't you try writing a function to rewrite the array, and if you have trouble, ask for help on StackOverflow? Most of us are happy to help you fix your code, but generally are not willing to act as unpaid short order programming staff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your array is contiguous, you can use the `"${array[@]}"` syntax to construct a new array:

```
array=('a' 'b' 'c');
echo "${array[@]}"; # prints: a b c
array=('d' "${array[@]}");
echo "${array[@]}"; # prints: d a b c
```

As [chepner mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959114/unshift-array-element-in-bash-script#comment65273395_38959226), the above method will collapse indices of sparse arrays:

```
array=([5]='b' [10]='c');
declare -p array; # prints: declare -a array='([5]="b" [10]="c")'
array=('a' "${array[@]}");
declare -p array; # prints: declare -a array='([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")'
```

(Fun fact: [PHP does that too](https://3v4l.org/RPa3b) - but then again, [it's PHP](http://phpsadness.com/) :P)

If you need to work with sparse arrays, you can iterate over the indices of the array manually (`${!array[@]}`) and  increase them by one (with `$((...+1))`):

```
old=([5]='b' [10]='c');
new=('a');
for i in "${!old[@]}"; do
    new["$(($i+1))"]="${old[$i]}";
done;
declare -p new; # prints: declare -a new='([0]="a" [6]="b" [11]="c")'
```

Answer (score 6):

Non-*bash* version:  *POSIX* shells don't really have arrays, excepting shell parameters, (i.e. *$1, $2, $3, ...*),but for those parameters this should work:

```
set - a b c ; echo $1 $3
```

Output:

```
a c
```

Now add "*foo*" to the beginning:

```
set - foo "$@" ; echo $1 $3
```

Output:

```
foo b
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, see the example below:

```
#!/bin/bash
MyArray=(Elem1 Elem2);
echo "${MyArray[@]}"
MyArray=(Elem0 "${MyArray[@]}")
echo "${MyArray[@]}"
```

As per @ghoti's comment, `declare -p MyArray` can be used to display the content of the array nicely. When invoked at the end of the script above, it outputs:

```
declare -a MyArray='([0]="Elem0" [1]="Elem1" [2]="Elem2")'
```

Comment: You may find that `declare -p MyArray` is a useful way of visualizing the contents of your array.

Comment: ...or at least `printf '%q\n' "${MyArray[@]}"` -- with `echo "${MyArray[@]}"`, you can't tell the difference between `MyArray=( hello world )` and `MyArray=( "hello world" )`